# Saving more than 1 excel sheet as a single PDF

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I looking to save more than 2 excel worksheets as a single PDF file. I have this code but it can save only single file, how to make it work so that it can pick 2 files and save it as a single PDF.

```
Sub CMSaveAsPDF()
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant

On Error GoTo errHandler
Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = Worksheets("Design")
strPath = wbA.path
If strPath = "" Then
strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

strFile = "Design" 
myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
(InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
    FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
    Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

      If myFile <> "False" Then
      wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & myFile
End If
End sub
```

Comment: if doing manually, we select the two sheets, then only save as pdf, for your code you can do the same

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I captured code using macro and added sheets name in array and it worked.Sheets(Array("Design", "Data")).Select

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub CMSaveAsPDF()
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant

On Error GoTo errHandler
Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = Worksheets("Design")
strPath = wbA.path
If strPath = "" Then
strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

strFile = "Design" 
myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
(InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
    FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
    Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

     If myFile <> "False" Then
     Sheets(Array("Design", "Data")).Select  ' Selected sheet names in array
      wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & myFile
End If
End sub
```

Answer (score 1):

After selecting multiple sheets, export the Activesheet.

```
Sub CMSaveAsPDF()
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant

On Error GoTo errHandler
Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = Worksheets("Design")
strPath = wbA.Path
If strPath = "" Then
strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

strFile = "Design"
myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
(InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
    FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
    Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

      If myFile <> "False" Then
      Sheets(Array("Design", "Data")).Select 'first multi sheets select
      'change to Activesheet
      ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & myFile
End If
End Sub
```